# Why does this return an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception?

Tags: java, list

I have a list in java,

```
List<CP> cp=cpp.getCP();
```

getCP method returns a list of CP (`List<CP>`)

I am trying to get a `CP` and modify it ands then add it back.

```
for(CP c:cp) {
    int index=cp.indexOf(c);
    c.setM_midRate(value);
    cp.set(index,c);
}
cpp.setCP(cp);
```

But set() gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why is that? I'm setting at the same position

Comment: Debug your code and you'll know why.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You never removed `c`; why do you need to "add it back"?

Comment: The exception should give you the index number too.

Comment: print the values of index inside for loop. You will for sure get an idea.

Comment: @shmosel I want to replace it

Comment: I would said `index` is -1. But the stack exception should tell you that.

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani With itself?

Comment: @shmosel after changing it. `c.setM_midRate(value);`

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani, you don't have to replace or set, remove those two lines of index, and things should work absolutely fine

Comment: It's still the same object.

Comment: @AxelH yes it is -1, but can ou please explain why is that? I am a beginner.

Comment: @Arvind so a modification while iterating makes changes to the original object? Is it a refernece to it?

Comment: This "-1" means not found, so `c` is not found by `cp.indexOf`.

Comment: It means `c` was not found in `cp`. I don't know how that's possible unless `cp` is modified by a concurrent thread.

Comment: Or maybe `CP.equals()` is broken such that an instance might not equal itself.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of this ? This doesn't make much sense. (Of course, the problem can be skipped since you don't need to `cp.set` the instance, you already have it at this specific position)

Comment: Okay I realised that for( CP c:cp) was actually CP c:cs and was iterating on a different list (cs) , hence the error. Apologies everyone. Nonetheless since I realised from here, it provides a reference to the original object I don't need the line anyway. Thanks all!!!

Comment: **So it was a typo in the end.** I suggest to edit the names of your variables ... have a class `CP` but name the collection `cp` is already a problem because I would guess that `cp` is an instance of `CP` not a collection of `CP`. Variable name are essential to keep the code easy to read.

Comment: yes i will do that now. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has some sneaky issues.

You used the enhanced for loop to iterate over elements. Then you use indexOf. Searching through the list this way will take a very long time, since each element looks for itself. You want to use a different type of loop. Let me introduce you to the list iterator.

```
ListIterator<CP> iterator = cp.listIterator;
while(iterator.hasNext())
//...
```

WAIT! This is not necessary at all. You see, every time you get a new cp object in your loop, you actually get the reference. So when you call `setM_midRate` it updates the same instance of the object. No need to find the index or put the object back in the list. So...

```
for(CP c:cp) {
    c.setM_midRate(value);
}
cpp.setCP(cp);
```

Comment: The question isn't about optimizing the code, it's about an exception being thrown.

Comment: You may not need cpp.setCP(cp); either depending on whether you have a copy of the lost or not from the getCPP method

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you, until a better one comes along

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani it's useful to understand why your original code was broken too. Debugging is an essential skill for a developer.

Comment: I like how you start saying that OP is using the for each loop but should use an iterator then ... state that this is easier with a for each loop... You complicate the explanation. All you need to mention is that `CP c` is a reference of the instance in the collection, change a value of `c` will change the value of the instance in the collection.

Comment: My point was to show that for his understanding of the problem he was using the wrong Loop but actually he was misunderstanding the problem the whole time so my first point was irrelevant

Comment: But I think it was still useful to have their because it shows a thought process